# How to extract the destination number using an Asterisk call file

Tags: asterisk

I'm new to Asterisk but I can make an outgoing call by generating a call file and moving it to the spool folder. I can even link it to an AGI script and get the call to do more things

The problem is I can see all the details including the CLI number in the cdrdb database but not the number it was calling. Only the letter 's' in the 'dst' column.

Also when I type "core show channels concise" I get a channel for the current outgoing call but it says "SIP/0001c" or something similar.

Is there something I should be putting into the call file or the AGI script that can pass the destination number on? Or should I be doing a dial plan here?

BTW calls are defiantly going through.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out

> The phone number you are dialling will not be stored in the CDR by * -
>   if you need this information for CDR processing you can set the
>   CallerID in the call file to this number and it will be stored.
>   However, this will present the person you are calling their own phone
>   number, which doesn't make much sense. A better solution might be to
>   put the number you are dialing in the Set: channel variable in the
>   .call file and later put it into the UserField of the CDR. See example
>   above in the first section.

So I think the best way would be to add a variable in your call file (as the text says), with the target, like:

```
Set: Target=5555555
```

Then, in your agi script, you will have a channel variable named **Target** with the value in question.

Get its contents via [GET VARIABLE](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/get+variable) or [GET FULL VARIABLE](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/get+full+variable), and in your agi script, add a custom CDR field by setting **CDR(myvariable)** with [SET VARIABLE "CDR(myvariablename)" "value"](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/set+variable)

This will get the value to the cdr, ready to be saved. You can try it out with the csv backend, by adding the custom field in **cdr_custom.conf**, for example adding **${CSV_QUOTE(${CDR(myvariablename)})}** at the end.

If you're using other cdr backends, you might have to look at the right documentation (for mysql -and probably the rest too-, you might get away by using the "**userfield**" column).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help and confirming that Asterisk can't store the value in CDR.

Would this method allow the value to appear in "core show channels concise"? Because I've though of another ugly workaround which is to add the number to the account name in the call file like this:

Account: myaccount.5555

That way I can use sql or php or whatever to select the account field and split it into account name and destination number

Would that be OK or is it a bad idea for some reason I haven't seen?

Comment: @TomHare sure :) Dont forget to accept the answer if it was useful. cheers!

Comment: @TomHare mm dont think so, this is a CDR field

Comment: @TomHare mm I wouldn't do it that way.. If you *really* want that, try using local channels, or even doing a core show channel <channelName> where you can see the "Target" value (actually all channel variables)

Comment: If I understand this right the channel name changes every time based on what I think is a hexadecimal code.

Comment: OK I've worked out how to extract Target from "show active channels" using your method. Can I add the target variable to userfield with the AGI script?

Comment: great! sure.. see the answer, just use SET VARIABLE with CDR(userfield)

Comment: Sorry but I'm still struggling...

I have echo 

"GET VARIABLE Target"

and

echo "SET VARIABLE \"CDR(userfield)\" \"Target\""

Is that right?